# Change literal dynamically in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I want to write a method that takes a literal, lets say

```
turn
```

end returns something like this

```
(my turn)
```

So, after that, if I call `eval`, scheme will call defined method `my` with parameter `turn`.

I did manage just to return some another literal or string, but I didn't manage to do what I wanted. And I didn't find any specification about something like this.

I assume I have somehow to use something like this: `` `(my,@param) ``  but it doesn't work.

`turn` is a symbol

Comment: In Scheme, `my(turn)` is not a function application - the correct way is `(my turn)`. Another thing: what do you mean by `literal`? String? Variable? Symbol?

Comment: +1 on the XY problem comment from @oscar-lopez . What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is not XY problem. I want to evaluate list of commands, and handle undefined literals using my own procedure.

Comment: I agree with Óscar and John Clements about the XY problem. Why are you attempting to "evaluate list of commands, and handle undefined literals using [your] own procedure"? There is a very high probability that there is a better way to solve that problem (the answer to the why).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, perhaps there's a simpler way to achieve what you *really* intend to do… Anyway, answering the question:

```
; we need to prevent the evaluation of the parameter,
; a normal procedure won't work here - we need a macro
(define-syntax method
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x) '(my x))))

; sample input
(define turn 9)
(define (my param) (+ 1 param))

; setup the evaluation namespace
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

; first test: `method` returns a non-evaluated expression
(method turn)
=> '(my turn)

; second test: evaluate the returned expression
(eval (method turn) ns)
=> 10
```